# Using count in nested block

Tags: terraform

Is there a way in Terraform to use the count param within a nested block? I don't want to create multiple instances of a resource, I want to generate a dynamic number of nested blocks with a resource. As an example:

```
variable "envNames" {
  type = "list"
}

variable "envValues" {
  type = "list"
}


resource "test_resource" "example" {

  # If length(var.envNames) == 5, I would want 5 env blocks
  env {
    count = "${length(var.envNames)}"

    name  = "${element(var.envNames, count.index)}"
    value = "${element(var.envValues, count.index)}"
  }

}
```

It looks like in terraform v0.12 I would be able to use the `dynamic` keyword on the block along with the `foreach` declaration and a map variable, but is there a way to do this in v0.11?

If it helps, this is for a Kubernetes Deployment resource.

Comment: Some resources allow you to do this in a super hacky way but at this point I'd honestly just wait for the 0.12 release rather than flailing around with a bunch of hacks. The alpha is already out if you want to try that.

Comment: I actually updated the Kubernetes provider to work with v0.12-alpha and ran into a bug with pulling remote state.